# Maven resource files, put java class files and property files in same directory

Tags: java, resources, maven

I have java class files and property files in the same directory.

src/main/java/com/berlin/Test.class

src/main/java/com/berlin/Test.properties

With the maven jar I build and the maven target, I want these to appear in the same directory.  but maven is placing the class files and property files in different places when I do 'mvn package'.

.. Output:
jar -tvf file.jar:

Sat Jun 11 08:24:32 EDT 2011 main/java/com/berlin/Test.properties

I want:
Sat Jun 11 08:24:32 EDT 2011 com/berlin/Test.properties
Sat Jun 11 08:24:32 EDT 2011 com/berlin/Test.class

...

Part of my pom:

```xml
<build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>           
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>            
        </plugins>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the Maven reasons, you should place properties file into src/main/resources, not in src/main/java directory (keeping the same subfolder structure).

That being said, to get what you want you need to replace (in your pom.xml) `src` with `src/main/java`. Not tested, but if you have problems please share.

Answer (score 1):

First you should place your resources into src/main/resources/com/berlin/Test.properties and your java source files into src/main/java/com/berlin/Test.java...Never put compiled classes into src/ folder... furthermore you should remove the configuration:

```
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
  <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
  <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

from your pom, cause you don't need it and furthermore it's wrong (Convention over configuration paradigm!). Take a look at the [default folder layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) in maven.

The Maven Way is to put the source files (*.java) into src/main/java, the resources src/main/resources. The unit test classes src/test/java and src/test/resources after compiling it will be put into target/classes or for the tests target/test-classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to popular opinion, and flying in the face of what others consider as "the maven reasons":

- It is in fact very useful to have resources in the exact same
  directories as the java files, and
- It is perfectly feasible to have
  maven place copies of these resource files in the exact same
  directories as the corresponding class files.

Here are the magical pom.xml incantations that will accomplish this:
(Assuming that your sources are in a directory called 'src')

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Beware that this will copy to the output folder every single file under 'src' which is not a java file. If you have more files that you do not want copied to the output folder, either add more exclusions, or replace '**/*' with a wildcard that only matches your resource files.

If you do the above, you can then have a class like the following, in the same package as the resources:

```
public class ResourceLocator
{
    public static URL getResourceUrl( String name )
    {
        URL url = ResourceLocator.class.getResource( name );
        assert url != null : name;
        return url;
    }
}
```