# .MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name

Tags: java, maven, resourcebundle

I'm using library called jnca to capture netflow udp packets sent from a router.

When it's imported in to a new project in IntellijIDea it works.

[image: JNCA]

Bet when that is used inside  a maven project it doesn't work and gives this exception.

[image: jnca]

Exception:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.wso2.event.adaptor.udp.jnca.etc.NetFlow, locale en_US
at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:795)
at org.wso2.event.adaptor.udp.jnca.cai.utils.Resources.<init>(Resources.java:24)
at org.wso2.event.adaptor.udp.jnca.cai.flow.collector.Collector.<clinit>(Collector.java:51)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at org.wso2.event.adaptor.udp.jnca.cai.flow.collector.Run.<clinit>(Run.java:14)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:113)
NetFlow.properties: Can't find bundle for base name org.wso2.event.adaptor.udp.jnca.etc.NetFlow, locale en_US
```

There is no package naming issues.

Problem is with this code segment

```
      try {

        resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("org.wso2.event.adaptor.udp.jnca.etc." + myName, Locale
                                             .getDefault());
    } catch (MissingResourceException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
        error(SuperString.exceptionMsg(exc.toString()));
    }
```

myName = Netflow

I have tried changing the path to the resource but it didn't work. 
And tried to include that netflow.properties file inside the maven project's resources folder it also didn't work

How to fix this

Thank you

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333363/loading-a-properties-file-from-java-package

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using Maven, properties files should be located inside src/main/resources not in src/main/java (see  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6316516/1431979))

So, for instance, if you have the following definition in your faces-config.xml (for using the msgs variable in your facelet pages) :

```
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>i18n.PanneauPrincipal</base-name>
        <var>msgs</var>
    </resource-bundle>
```

Or if you load the resource files programmatically :

```
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n.PanneauPrincipal", locale);
```

Then the PanneauPrincipal_en.properties file should be located in the following directory :

```
    src/main/resources/i18n
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this. Moving my package to my src/main/resources fixed the same issue I was having. This should be the accepted answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Copy your .properties files to the resources folder in the root (not inside packages)
And then in your code when you want to access these .properties files don't mention any package name. just only the name of the .properties files in enough.
like this:

```
 resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle(myName, Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: Lol I've done this many times and i was going crazy because it was not working this time. I unintentionally created the "resources" folder inside "java" folder. Upvoting