# Loading files from Resource folder using java jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-3

I have download.sh file in my src/main/resource folder in maven project and I am reading it through below code

```
 ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
 File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("download.sh").getFile());
```

The file is reading when I run this as the standalone application.

If I run this as application using jar ex:-

java -jar runScript.jar SCHEMA_NAME

**/Users/IdeaProjects/RunScript/target/file:/Users/IdeaProjects/RunScript/target/RunScripts.jar!/download.sh": error=2, No such file or directory**

Can anyone help me in reading  file from resource when executing with jar

Comment: how do you package your jar?

Comment: by running mvn clean install @Kirill Simonov

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this error happens when you try to read the file. This is because resources inside your jar are not files but streams. So you should use

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("download.sh");
```

and then read that stream, for example:

```
InputStream resourceStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("download.sh")
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resourceStream));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // do something
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not packaging your resources along with your jar. Please verify your jar contains the resource file (download.sh) with

```
jar -tvf <yourfile.jar> | grep -i download
```

Comment: resource folder not created in jar. But all the files included in the immediate directory

Comment: @Ganesh That doesn't make sense. If the resources aren't in the JAR, why are you using `ClassLoader.getResource()`?

Comment: @Ganesh, If you are using maven, try these links : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316462/maven-resource-files-put-java-class-files-and-property-files-in-same-directory (or) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637532/maven-how-to-place-resource-file-together-with-jar

Answer (score 0):

Resources are *not* files. You can get their URLs, or input streams, but nothing you can do will turn a resource in a JAR file into a file on the disk that you can use with `File`. Short of unpacking the JAR file, that is.